# Can I use steganography to detect data loss that occurs due to gradual degradation in quality in sequential printing of black and white noise texture?

Tags: steganography

I want to detect original print and a reproduced print. So if I embed some information in this kind of noise texture, after reproducing the original print there might be some loss in information due to degradation in quality in printing. So my question is, Can I use steganography to measure information loss? So I can distinguish between original print and a reproduced print.

[image]

Comment: Yes by intuition.  I would expect the entropy of the image to reduce every reprint.  Otherwise you'd be able to keep photocopying photocopies ad infinitum.  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ may be a more informed place for the mechanics of image degradation though.  There may be some relevant stuff in my other answer to you too.

Comment: I'm sure that you realise, but an image like this is already effectively tagged "steggo here!"  A series of these on Friendface would need quite a nifty explanation/context.